# Bootstrap Dropdown Accordion z-index problem

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm using bootstrap and i have this problem where if i place a dropdown into an accordion, when i click to trigger the dropdown menu of the first accordion header, the dropdown menu is vizually partially blocked by the dropdown of the second accordion header.

I've made a simplified snippet of what my problem is, beacuse it's easier to show the problem than explaining it.

You can try to view the following html. Notice, that when you click on the first dropdown "Turn On/Off" you can't see the whole dropdown menu.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <div class="accordion">
          <div class="accordion-item">
              <h2 class="accordion-header position-relative">
                <div class="position-absolute top-50 translate-middle" style="right: 0; z-index: 4;">
                  <div class="btn-group position-relative" role="group" aria-label="Basic mixed styles example">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="black" class="bi bi-power text-center" viewBox="0 2 16 16"><path d="M7.5 1v7h1V1h-1z"/><path d="M3 8.812a4.999 4.999 0 0 1 2.578-4.375l-.485-.874A6 6 0 1 0 11 3.616l-.501.865A5 5 0 1 1 3 8.812z"/></svg>
                      Turn on/off
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Turn on</button></li>
                      <li><button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Turn off</button></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>  
                <button style="--bs-accordion-btn-focus-box-shadow: 0" class="accordion-button collapsed bg-primary text-white" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                    <div class="badge bg-light text-dark me-2 border p-2">
                      Online
                    </div>    
                    <strong>Server1</strong>
                </button>
              </h2>
          </div>
          <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header position-relative">
              <div class="position-absolute top-50 translate-middle" style="right: 0; z-index: 4;">
                <div class="btn-group position-relative" role="group" aria-label="Basic mixed styles example">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20" fill="black" class="bi bi-power text-center" viewBox="0 2 16 16"><path d="M7.5 1v7h1V1h-1z"/><path d="M3 8.812a4.999 4.999 0 0 1 2.578-4.375l-.485-.874A6 6 0 1 0 11 3.616l-.501.865A5 5 0 1 1 3 8.812z"/></svg>
                    Turn on/off
                  </button>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Turn on</button></li>
                    <li><button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Turn off</button></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>  
              <button style="--bs-accordion-btn-focus-box-shadow: 0" class="accordion-button collapsed bg-primary text-white" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                  <div class="badge bg-light text-dark me-2 border p-2">
                    Online
                  </div>    
                  <strong>Server2</strong>
              </button>
            </h2>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've spend hours trying to find a solution, by countless searches, but i am unable to find a solution to the problem.

I've tested it on both firefox and chrome, but it's the same problem.

I've tried manually setting the z-index value on ul, li and button tags to 1000, but with no changes. I've also tried messing with the z-index and position on different elements while using developer tools to confirm changes, but without any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `z-index` on the dropdowns can't help, as the it's the parent elements that set the stacking order. So to get it to work, you could do this:

```css
.accordion-item {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.accordion-item:first-child {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Now the first `.accordion-item` element has a higher `z-index` than the second one, and its contents like dropdowns will sit above those of the second one.

Comment: If i'm understanding you correctly your solution is to add <style>
      .accordion-item {
        position: relative;
      }

      .accordion-item:first-child {
        z-index: 2;
      }
    </style> Unfortunalty this doesn't seem to fix the problem. Does it work for you?

Comment: Sorry, what I posted above wasn't exactly what I used in testing. I also added `z-index: 1` to the second `.accordion-item`. I've updated the code above. If you do what you did before but add that extra line of `z-index: 1`, it should work for you, as it did for me when texting on your code. :-)

Comment: That said, this solution is really for the demo you posted.If there are more `.accordion-item` elements, something more sophisticated will be needed, but hopefully the main principle will be clear: that for the contents on one `accordion-item` to overlap another, it must have a higher z-index than the one its overlapping.

Comment: It works exactly as intended. Thank you so much.